# How to get data from db placed on k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, frends

I want to get data from Magento 2 placed on Kubernetes.
In order to Sql ExecuteQuery i need [frends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkfsI.png)

Where i can take **myServerAddress** ?
What should I take into account for such a connection ?

I have no idea how to do it, so maybe someone have such experience and share information where i can get **myServerAddress** and what should i do on k8s side to allow such queries to the database

Comment: To query MySql database you have to use Frends Task for it like MySQL.ExecuteQuery, not  Sql.ExecuteQuery or MicrosoftSQL.ExecuteQuery that are for Microsofts SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Your **DB service name** will be the **myServerAddress** for you if you are running the query somewhere inside the cluster only.

If you are running an outside query and your database is in **K8s** and not exposed you might have to expose your **Db** service. You can change your service type to **LoadBalancer**. Make sure this will expose database publicly.

Here example for **MySQL**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

So the service name is MySQL and if I want to connect to it I can use the service name internally **mysql**.

Ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/

if you have some client tools installed on the same K8s cluster like **Adminer** you can use the **service name** as the connection Host.